# import Appkit framework in iphone Application

Tags: iphone, ios4

i am new in iphone technology , i want to use class NSspeechSynthesizer  from Appkit framework, but when i import this framework in my application , it give 7 error in my application.

please provide me help on this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't import AppKit, it is not available on the iPhone, it's an OS X library.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/2010/09/08/voicerecognition-for-the-iphone/), it supports for text-to-speech for iOS.

The text-to-speech library OpenEars uses is called [CMU Flite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/), and you could install it directly, but the documentation on the CMU Flite site is a bit poor if you are not very experienced.

I would go for OpenEars, because they have a nice script doing most of the work for you.